# Problem with breaking a loop, password generator

Tags: python

guys, I am having problems with my code. What I want to do is allow my code to give the user only 3 attempts to enter a password. What am I doing wrong?

```
import re

attempts = 3

def validate():
     while attempts <= 3 and True:

        password = input("Enter a password that meets all of the requirments: ")
        if len(password) < 6:
            print("Your password must be at lest 6-20 letters")
            attempt +=1
            print("attempt", attempt)
        elif re.search('[0-9]',password) is None:
            print("Your password must have a number in it")
        elif re.search('[A-Z]',password) is None: 
            print("Your password must contain a capital letter in it")
        else:
            print("All password conditions have been met, great job your password is acceptable")
            break

validate()
```

Answer (score 1):

should work. You don't need to check all requirements if pass already does not meet one of them. And you actually don't need True in this while loop.

```
import re

attempts = 3

def validate(): 
   for attempt in range(3):

    password = input("Enter a password that meets all of the requirments: ")
    if len(password) < 6:
        print("Your password must be at lest 6-20 letters")
        print("attempt", attempt)
        continue
    if re.search('[0-9]',password) is None:
        print("Your password must have a number in it")
        continue
    if re.search('[A-Z]',password) is None: 
        print("Your password must contain a capital letter in it")
        continue
    print("All password conditions have been met, great job your password is acceptable")
    return
```

Comment: The logic would make more sense if those two `elif`s were `if`s instead.

Answer (score 1):

So, a few things.

You should probably start your attempts variable at 1 with the <= check. Also, and True isn't required here. That's always going to evaluate to whatever attempts <= 3 evaluates to.

You only increment attempts on 1/3 error cases.

You should also have a way to not enter attempts when the password is correct. Maybe instead of and True, you write <= 3 and not already_valid or something w/ initial state set to False

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the attempts as an argument to the function, instead of trying to use a global variable.

Also, I would separate the logic for the password requirement validation from the number of attempts, something like this will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re

def validate(password):
  if len(password) < 6:
    print("Your password must be at lest 6-20 letters")
    return False
  if re.search('[0-9]',password) is None:
    print("Your password must have a number in it")
    return False
  if re.search('[A-Z]',password) is None: 
    print("Your password must contain a capital letter in it")
    return False
  print("All password conditions have been met, great job your password is acceptable")
  return True

def definePassword(attempts):
  for i in range(attempts):
    pwd = input("Enter a password that meets all of the requirments: ")
    if validate(pwd):
      print("Your password was defined: " + pwd)
      return pwd
    else:
      print("Failed attempt " + str(i))
  return False

password = definePassword(3)
if not password: print("Failed to set up a password")
```

the `validate()` function will receive a password as an argument and check its validity, the `definePassword()` function will receive the number of allowed attempts.

I hope this approach helps